# How to remove duplicate arrays in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 7]];
```

how to remove duplicate arrays from the given array? The first two elements of the array are the same. I couldn't fix it with the set.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want a general solution or just for sub-array entries that contain numbers? If only for numbers, do we need to consider `NaN` values?

Answer (score 5):

Use method `filter()`.

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 7]];
const arrNoDouble = arr.filter((a = {}, b => !(a[b] = b in a)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrNoDouble));
```

Comment: this works because by setting the array as a key in the a object you are implicitly converting to string and comparing strings. It is nice, but the answer could use some explanation as it is not obvious at all

Comment: This is dangerous if applied to string data [that might convert to the same string](https://jsbin.com/zofovoxelu/1/edit?js,console). `[1, 2]` (or `["1", "2"]`) converts to the same as `["1,2"]` and this the two are considered "equivalent" when they aren't. Same thing with `["3,4", "5"]` and `["3", "4", "5"]`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this:

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [7, 7]
];
const newArr = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse)


console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This, or `[...new Map(arr.map(x => [JSON.stringify(x), x])).values()` to avoid `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the array of arrays into an array of strings with `JSON.stringify`. This way, the `Set`'s filtering magic can filter the values correctly as they are primitive values.

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 7]];
let el = arr.map(a => JSON.stringify(a));
let set = new Set(el);
let unique = Array.from(set, JSON.parse);

// one liner
let uniqueArr = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify)), JSON.parse);
console.log(uniqueArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method to create a new array `newarr` without **duplicates** from your current array `arr`:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 7]];
const m = {}
const newarr = []

  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    const v = arr[i];
    if (!m[v]) {
      newarr.push(v);
      m[v]=true;
    }
  }

 console.log(newarr);
```